# Icons in jstree using types are not redrawn within create

Tags: icons, jstree, redraw

I use panel with several accordions.

Each time the accordion is opened a tree with the content is created.

This works well.

But when the tree is displayed in the accordion pane jstree uses the themeicon instead of the icon defined in the data-jstree.

Within the first expand of a folder the icons are redrawn and shows the correct icons. A simple `refresh()` or `redraw()` after the creation does not work.

Where is the problem?

How can I force the use of the type icons?

This is the part of the code:

```
    <!--added as html code in the content pane of the accordion-->
    <div class="tree" id="panel_tree_div">
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "book", "opened" : false, "icon" : "" }' key="a=_03&amp;i=1" >Programmieren
            <ul>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "book", "opened" : false, "icon" : "" }' key="a=_03&amp;" >Javascript
                    <ul>
                        <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "book", "opened" : false, "icon" : "" }' key="a=_03&amp;" >JQuery
                            <ul>
                                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file"}' key="a=_03&amp;i=10" >UI Layout JQuery Plugin</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file"}' key="a=_03&amp;i=2" >TnT's</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

This is the code of the click event of the accordion:

```
    $("h3","#accordion1").click( function(evt, ui) {
        intAccIndex = $("#accordion1").accordion("option", "active");
        if (intPreviousActiveIndex == intAccIndex) {
            // We can stop here. We do not want to load the same thing twice
            return ;
        }
        // Get the panel content from the server
        strAnswer= send_request("c=2&panIdx="+(intAccIndex));
        // destroy a former tree or other elements, if exists ( in the former active panel)
        if (intPreviousActiveIndex != -1 && intPreviousActiveIndex != intAccIndex) {
            objPrevContent = $("#accordion1").find("#accordion1_content_" + intPreviousActiveIndex);
            objPrevContent.empty();
        }
        // Save the current index
        intPreviousActiveIndex= intAccIndex;
        // Get the content element of the current selected panel
        objContent = $("#accordion1").find("#accordion1_content_" + intAccIndex);
        // Make sure the content area is empty
        objContent.empty();
        // Deploy the new panel content
        objContent.append(strAnswer);

        if ( ! $('#panel_tree_div') ) {
            // It seems the current content has no tree element
            // We can stop here
            return;
        }                                           
        // Now the html elements are in place
        // We can add the js object(s) of the tree
        // create the tree using the new applied tree sceleton in the accordion pane
        $.jstree.create( $('#panel_tree_div'), {
            "core": {
                "multiple" : false,
                "expand_selected_onload" : true
            },
            "themes": {
                "name" : 'tools',
                "variant" : 'small',
                "stripes" : true,
                "dots" : false
            },
            "types" : {
                    'lockedFolder' : {
                        'icon': '<c:url value="/css/jstree_themes/default/lockedFolder.png" />'
                        },
                    "default": {

                    },
                    "custom": {

                    },                                                          
                    "folder" : {
                        "icon" : "file-folder"
                    },
                    "book" : {
                        "icon" : "file-book" 
                    },
                    "file" : {
                        "icon" : " file-small"
                    },                                                          
                    "doc" : {
                        "icon" : "file"
                    }                                                       
            },
            "plugins" : [ "state", "types"]
            //, "plugins" : [ "checkbox", "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",   "state", "types", "wholerow"]
        });

        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree().on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {

            strCall=(data.node['li_attr']['key'] != 'undefined')? data.node['li_attr']['key'] : "";
            if (strCall !="") {
                // set title
                oContentTitle= $("#content_title");
                oContentTitle.empty();
                intAccIndex = $("#accordion1").accordion("option", "active");
                strCaption=  $("#accordion1 h3").eq(intAccIndex).text();
                // call page
                strAnswer = send_request(strCall);
                oContentTitle.append( strCaption );
                oIFrame=$("#content");
                oIFrameDoc= oIFrame[0].contentDocument || oIFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
                oIFrameDoc.write(strAnswer);
                oIFrameDoc.close(); 
            }

        });

        // because the settings in themes does not work!
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('set_theme','tools');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('set_theme_variant','small');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_icons');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_dots');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_stripes');    //? no stripes
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('redraw',true);     // no effect!


        //$("#accordion1").accordion("refresh");
        objAcc.accordion({ active: intAccIndex});   

    }); // end of accordion click function
```

Picture: after the create:

[image: Picture: after the click/expand of the first folder]

Picture: after the click/expand of the first folder:

[image: Picture: after the click/expand of the first folder]

Comment: I think if you asked a more compact question, reducing the question to the essence of the problem, you would get more help. After all people here like to help but ideally it they don't want to spend an hour just to read the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a/the solution.
The `$.jstree.create( $('#panel_tree_div'), { options });`
function works not the same way as `$('#panel_tree_div').jstree({ options});` or the event binding is different.

After this modification it works without `refresh()` or `redraw()`.

This is the modified code:

```
    $("h3","#accordion1").click( function(evt, ui) {
        intAccIndex = $("#accordion1").accordion("option", "active");
        if (intPreviousActiveIndex == intAccIndex) {
            // We can stop here. We do not want to load the same thing twice
            return ;
        }

        // Get the panel content from the server
        strAnswer= send_request("c=2&panIdx="+(intAccIndex));

        // destroy a former tree or other elements, if exists ( in the former active panel)
        if (intPreviousActiveIndex != -1 && intPreviousActiveIndex != intAccIndex) {
            objPrevContent = $("#accordion1").find("#accordion1_content_" + intPreviousActiveIndex);
            objPrevContent.empty();
        }
        // Save the current index
        intPreviousActiveIndex= intAccIndex;
        // Get the content element of the current selected panel
        objContent = $("#accordion1").find("#accordion1_content_" + intAccIndex);
        // Make sure the content area is empty
        objContent.empty();
        // Deploy the new panel content
        objContent.append(strAnswer);

        if ( ! $('#panel_tree_div') ) {
            // It seems the current content has no tree element
            // We can stop here
            return;
        }                                           
        // Now the html elements are in place
        // We can add the js object(s) of the tree
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree({
        //$.jstree.create( $('#panel_tree_div'), { // does not redraw
                "core": {
                    "multiple" : false,
                    "expand_selected_onload" : true,
                    "id" : 1
                },
                "themes": {
                    "name" : 'tools',
                    "variant" : 'small',
                    "stripes" : true,
                    "dots" : false
                },
                "types" : {
                        'lockedFolder' : {
                            'icon': '<c:url value="/css/jstree_themes/default/lockedFolder.png" />'
                            },
                        "default": {

                        },
                        "custom": {

                        },                                                          
                        "folder" : {
                            "icon" : "file-folder"
                        },
                        "book" : {
                            "icon" : "file-book"  //'<c:url value="../libs/jquery/jstree_themes/tools/book.png" />'
                        },
                        "file" : {
                            "icon" : "file-small"
                        },                                                          
                        "doc" : {
                            "icon" : "file"
                        }                                                       
                },
                "plugins" : [ "state", "types"]
                //, "plugins" : [ "checkbox", "contextmenu", "dnd", "search",   "state", "types", "wholerow"]
        })
        .on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
            //alert("hello");
            // do something
        })
        .on('changed.jstree', function(e, data) {
            if (isset(data.node)) {
                strCall=(isset(data.node['li_attr']['key']))? data.node['li_attr']['key'] : "";
            } else {
                strCall="";
            }
            if (strCall !="") {

                // set title
                oContentTitle= $("#content_title");
                oContentTitle.empty();
                intAccIndex = $("#accordion1").accordion("option", "active");
                strCaption=  $("#accordion1 h3").eq(intAccIndex).text();
                // call page
                strAnswer = send_request(strCall);
                oContentTitle.append( strCaption );
                oIFrame=$("#content");
                oIFrameDoc= oIFrame[0].contentDocument || oIFrame[0].contentWindow.document;
                oIFrameDoc.write(strAnswer);
                oIFrameDoc.close(); 
            }
        });

        // because the settings in themes does not work!
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('set_theme','tools');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('set_theme_variant','small');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_icons');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_dots');
        $('#panel_tree_div').jstree('show_stripes'); //?
        objAcc.accordion({ active: intAccIndex});                                           
    }); // end of accordion click function
```